# What exactly does the "per mole" unit of heat of atomization mean?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, reference-request, erratum

I am facing a confusion in the definition of the standard enthalpy of atomization. The confusion arises because of the "per mole" in its units ($\pu{kJ mol^-1}$).

**My question**: When I say "per mole", do I mean "per mole" of the *product* or per mole of the *reactant*?

When I mean **"per mole" of the product**, my representative reaction for $\Delta H_\mathrm{a}^\circ$ is:

$$\ce{1/4 P4(s) -> P (g)}$$

And when I mean **"per mole" of the reactant**, my representative reaction for $\Delta H_\mathrm{a}^\circ$ is:

$$\ce{P4 (s) -> 4P (g)}$$

Using either of them leads to different calculations involving Hess's law or other chemical reactions, hence I feel there is a need to resolve this confusion.

---

To add to this confusion, NCERT Chemistry (Part 1 page 171) writes:

> It is the enthalpy change on breaking **one mole of bonds** completely to obtain atoms in the gas phase.

but then gives a representative reaction as:

$$\ce{CH4 -> C(g) + 4H(g)}$$

which involves breaking **4 moles** of bonds instead.

---

If someone could write the correct definition of the standard enthalpy of atomization, with more than one reputed reference to back their claim, it'd definitely resolve this confusion.

Comment: Here per mole means per mole of product formed (as this is atomization). Standard enthalpy of atomization is the enthalpy change when 1 mol of gaseous atoms is formed from its element in its defined physical state under standard conditions (298.15K, 1 atm).

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_atomization),

> Standard enthalpy of atomization is the enthalpy change when $1$ mole of gaseous atoms is formed from its element in its defined physical state under standard conditions $(\pu{298.15K}, \pu{1 bar})$.

$\Delta H_{\text{at}}^{\circ}$ focuses on the production of $1$ mole of atoms from the element. Hence it's defined for the reaction:

$\ce{\dfrac{1}{8}S8 ->S}$

but not for the reaction:

$\ce{S8 -> 8S}$

So whenever you see the term "per mole", it is, by definition, implicitly referring to the product and not to the reactant.